# Tengo este error del gestor pip " is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pip, anaconda3

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchaudio-0.8.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: torchaudio-0.8.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Estaba intentando bajar los archivos de pytorch en un anaconda viejo, porque estoy usando un pytorch viejo (la 8.0) porque es el que es compatible con mi GPU.

https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch_stable.html
Los estaba intentando bajar de aqui.

Tambien ya actualice el gestor pip, pera descartar el posible problema, pero sigue pasando lo mismo

```
(base) C:\Users\MIPC\Desktop\MATI\Vtuber_HP\torch-for-cuda-8>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
```

Porque pasa esto? y que debo hacer?

Comment: No es problema de la versión de pip, sino de tu windows. ¿No será un windows 32bits?

Comment: yo pense lo mismo pero no es de 64 bits

Comment: al final con poniendo pip install torchvision y pip install torchaudio funciono, pero no funciona con pip install pytorch